# I am getting a parsing error in compiling my Vue project

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, babeljs, eslint

error  Component name "Header" should always be multi-word  vue/multi-word-component-names

[image: 1]

Comment: Googling "vue/multi-word-component-names" will yield an answer faster than posting an image here.

Answer (score 0):

Add an explicit line to disable this:
`// eslint-disable-next-line vue/multi-word-component-names`
as in the sample code

```
export default {
  // eslint-disable-next-line vue/multi-word-component-names
  name: "Header"
}
```